# How can we store twitter HomeTimeline tweets into MSSQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created Asp.net application in that I gets authentication token and secret to get twitter timeline. 
I succesfully getting all user home tweets. 
 
I want to store all tweets from user's home timeline in some interval(eq. xx seconds) asynchronously into my database.

How it will done?

Answer (score 0):

why reinvent the wheel?, this app (although php) is an archive for twitter.
lots of similar tools around too.

http://pongsocket.com/tweetnest/

Comment: Hello @4t4, I want to do some action/event on tweets from my database. Is any other C# related apps?